# How to show new sliding window on an event | Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application which have recycler view item.
I want to show on recyler view item click and new window contains the details of item and should reveal itself from bottom bar upto almost half of the height of screen.

Attaching an snapshot of an application app, i want to have same functionality as shown in below snippets.

[image]
[image]

Requirments are:
1) As seen in first image on click on recycler view item new window should pop up
2) New pop window should be scrollable, should scroll upto max half of the screen
3) New pop window should not go away on clicking any where on its screen.
4) New pop window should dismiss only if clicked or touched the screen outside of pop
up window.

I am new to android development, i am struggling for few weeks with my above requirment.
Can anybody help me here?